# How to supress certain warnings when running node / nodemon?

Tags: node.js, output, warnings, bluebird, nodemon

I am using highland. In my project, I have replaced the native promise implementation with bluebird. Now, my application produces a lot of warnings, by spamming the console with:

```
(node:1503) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at usr/src/marketing-tasks/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:517:24 but was not returned from it, see http://goo gl/rRqMUw
    at new Promise (/usr/src/marketing-tasks/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
```

I am aware there might be a problem that should be solved, yet currently my streams work as expected. So for now, whenever I call my script via either `node` or `nodemon`, I just want to not have these warnings in my output.

How to not show certain warnings when running node?

Comment: Have you tried setting `BLUEBIRD_WARNINGS=0` when running the app, as mentioned at the bottom of the config doc [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also created [an issue on github](https://github.com/caolan/highland/issues/588) and there it was explicated that the warning was a false positive, it has been handled nontheless. Updating to highland to v2.10.2 should also the issue without having to disable bluebird's warning entirely.

---

[Bluebird warning logging can be modified at different places via environment variables](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/environment-variables.html).

There are multiple that can enable it, e.g. via:

```
NODE_ENV='development'
```

which is the case on my development stack.

In order to explicitly deactivate that warning I set:

```
 BLUEBIRD_WARNINGS=0
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a Bluebird warning. You should be able to turn it off with something like:

```
require('bluebird').config({warnings: {wForgottenReturn: false}});
```

But probably it would be better in the long run to add something to the actual code that causes that warning because that code you can be sure works fine but later you may add something else that should trigger the warning.

But of course sometimes you just know what you're doing and you want to turn off the warning.

Also you may use my [caught](https://www.npmjs.com/package/caught) module here - it was designed to suppress a completely different type of warnings but maybe it can be used here as well.

Comment: Thanks, this brought me into the right direction. I find configuring it via env variables better though :)